# gdb: incorrect exit code

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb

when inserting this code's executable:

```
section .data
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
   movl $1,%eax
   mov $27,%ebx
   int $0x80
```

To `gdb` and running it - it outputs:
`[Inferior 1 (process 13321) exited with code 033]`

But that's of course not the right status code, but `27`... also when running the executable (outside of `gdb`) and then `echo $?` it says `27` too.
Do you have any idea why it's acting like that?

Comment: 033 (in octal) is 27 (in decimal).

Comment: Unrelated to Petr's correct answer, I assume `int $0x8` should be `int $0x80` and that copy/paste cut off the `0`?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yeah that's true. I didn't notice that, thanks!